# Какого рода слово аватар?

Tags: семантика

Картинку около имени я называю иногда аватар, иногда - аватарка. Как же правильно? 
Впрочем, ответ у меня на экране: второе слово подчеркнуто красным. Но оно мне нравится больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как это после фильма Кэмерона ни странно, "аватарка" будет более правильным вариатом, чем "аватар".

Дело в том, что ещё до всяких компьтеров был индуистский термин **аватара**, который именно в таком виде и закрепился в русском языке. Означает это слово что-то наподобе проявления божества в более низких сферах. Вроде христианского воплощения одной из ипостасей Бога в Иисусе Христе, хоть и со своими особенностями.

Американцы использовали этот термин у себя в виде *avatar*, изначально для обозначения игрового персонажа пользователя, в таком виде слово и проникло к нам вторично.

В общем, сейчас чаще используют *аватар* в мужском роде, *аватарку* в женском, но в словарях пока что только **аватара**.

Answer (score 5):

В орфографическом словаре Лопатина как раз "аватара". А "аватарка" получается - уменьшительно-ласкательное. В  русский язык пришло, по-моему, из английского 
(avatar  - олицетворение), как и другие компьютерные термины. Слово новое и вполне может быть закрепиться как "аватарка" по аналогии с "картинка", да и на слух приятнее, не такое грубое.

Answer (score 1):

Гм... Вообще, сложный и спорный вопрос. Как я понимаю, само слово произошло от индийского термина "Аватара" — воплотившееся божество. Но куда потом делать буква А на конце, не понятно. Чаще сейчас (особенно благодаря фильму) можно слышать слово "аватар", мужского рода, а "аватарка" — вроде как просторечное.
А что скажут знатоки-филологи?